# How to remove an application "tile" from Anaconda Navigator

Tags: anaconda

How to remove "oracle data science service" tile from anaconda navigator

ibm_watson:
is_available: false
pycharm_pro:
is_available: false
deepnote:
is_available: false
datalore:
is_available: false
qtconsole:
is_available: false
dataspell:
is_available: false
rstudio:
is_available: false
console_shortcut_miniconda:
is_available: false
powershell_shortcut_miniconda:
is_available: false
anaconda_notebooks:
is_available: false
orange3:
is_available: false
notebook:
is_available: false
glueviz:
is_available: false
oracle:
is_available: false

Comment: This question will probably be answered more quickly if you pose the question on the Anaconda community website, assuming one exists.

Answer (score 0):

From [Configuring Navigator tiles](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/navigator/tutorials/custom-tiles/):

Depending on your operating system, the configuration file can be created or edited at the following locations:

```
    Windows: %APPDATA%\.anaconda\navigator\applications\
    macOS and Linux: ~/.anaconda/navigator/applications/
```

Each configuration file must be in a .yaml` format, but your files can be named anything (within the character limits for files in your operating system).

There are a few default applications that are registered in Navigator:

```
PyCharm Community - pycharm_ce
PyCharm Professional - pycharm_pro
VS Code - vscode
Datalore - datalore
IBM Watson Studio Cloud - ibm_watson
```

Use these identifier keys to hide the above default applications within Navigator.
Hiding existing tiles

Navigator contains some default applications that can be hidden by a config file. To hide one of these applications from the Navigator Home tab:

Create a new config file (named something like config.yaml or hidden_apps.yaml) or edit an existing file.
Add something like the following:

```
        vscode:
            is_available: false
```

In this example, the VS Code application tile will be hidden from users in the Navigator Home tab.

Comment: ok, I have disabled all tiles but unable to disable "oracle data science service" from Prompt. I have used below code in config.yaml file but not working
oracle_data_science_service:
is_available: false

Comment: As i indicated previously, This question will probably be answered more completely if you pose the question on the Anaconda community website